# Java timer that can pause and resume?

Tags: java, timer, simulation

I'm working on a personal project that simulates a grocery store checkout. I currently have a timer that creates a new customer every few seconds or so and adds them to a queue. I need another that checks if there is an open lane, and if so removes the next in line and sends it to the checkout.

Ideally I'd have it so if every lane is in use, the function would pause but from some research it doesn't seem I can pause a timer. So my question would be, what is the best way to have a function pause, wait for an open lane, and then resume. Would I even need a timer or threading, or am I just overthinking this.

Just as an example with some code for visualizing.

```
                for(int i =0; i < open.size(); i++){
                    if(marked[i] == false){
                        marked[i] = true;
                        System.out.println("Lane " + (i+1) + " is serving customer: " + temp.get());
                        break;
                    }
                }else{
                        \\WAIT UNTIL OPEN LANE
```

So it runs through the lanes to find an open lane. If nothing is open then I want it to wait until one opens and then start up again.

Comment: You could have a timer that does not pause, that does something when there are *both* empty lanes and waiting customers, and otherwise tries again later. Or you could do the same thing when a lane becomes newly open -- event-based rather than time-based.

Comment: Your question makes no sense to me.  Why would you want to tie the speed of your simulation model to real-world time via a timer?  Why would customers stop arriving just because the lanes are all in use?  I'd recommend looking at something like [this tutorial](http://www.informs-sim.org/wsc06papers/001.pdf) to see how simulation event scheduling can be handled in a language such as Java.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I should have been clearer, a new customer is created at a set interval regardless of if the lanes are full or not. Each lane I have is an object with each lane taking a different amount of time to serve a customer. So at one point there may be no available lanes, and I was wondering what the best way to handle that would be. Should I just keep running a loop and check to see if there is an available loop, or can I use something like .wait until a lane opens up and then notify it to start. I've never done a real time simulation before so that's where the confusion is.

Comment: Read the linked tutorial.  Do not use a loop and repeatedly check, use event scheduling to determine when things happen.  That way you can painlessly skip over all the times when nothing is happening.  The tutorial even has an example with a queueing system.  In Java.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I didn't see your post, but that is exactly what I'm looking for thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use Multi Threading with try catch and in the body of **catch(...){}** handle the Lan flow.
Initially start two threads one for waiting one for serving when waiting thread gets response call responding thread and waiting thread must be in infinite while loop.

```
...

while(true){
System.out.println("WAIT UNTIL OPEN LANE");
lan = getNewLane();
new Responsethread(lan).start();
}

...
```

Comment: Ah ok. I havn't done multi-threading before but I was looking to start learning so I guess this as good a practice as any.

Comment: Also just to clarify, I want one tread that is "while the lane is open do this," and while no lanes are open do wait?